# Save image to disk with WinJS

Tags: javascript, winjs

I convert a canvas to an image and now I want to save the image to disk.
My question is:
Can I save or download the image to user disk? 
I'm use WinJS -- JavaScript

Comment: You can, but you need user interaction to select the file location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150595.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. As posted by Kraig for virtually the same question at [social.msdn.com: Saving a Canvas as an image in Windows 8](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/cf8c17dc-68d4-4777-951f-bb7f0665bd06/saving-a-canvas-as-an-image-in-windows-8)

```
var Imaging = Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
picker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.picturesLibrary;
picker.fileTypeChoices.insert("PNG file", [".png"]);
var imgData, fileStream = null;
picker.pickSaveFileAsync().then(function (file) {            
    if (file) {
        return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);                
    } else {
        return WinJS.Promise.wrapError("No file selected");
    }
}).then(function (stream) {
    fileStream = stream;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");            
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    return Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(Imaging.BitmapEncoder.pngEncoderId, stream);
}).then(function (encoder) {
    //Set the pixel data--assume "encoding" object has options from elsewhere
    encoder.setPixelData(encoding.pixelFormat, encoding.alphaMode,
        encoding.width, encoding.height, encoding.dpiX, encoding.dpiY,
        new Uint8Array(imgData.data));
    //Go do the encoding
    return encoder.flushAsync();
}).done(function () {
    //Make sure to do this at the end
    fileStream.close();  
}, function () {
    //Empty error handler (do nothing if the user canceled the picker
});
```

Comment: Wichi pixel format should I use in "encoder.setPixelData" function?